# when using feathers express, it gives page not found error #2355

Tags: reactjs, feathersjs, react-boilerplate

I'm intergrating feathers js both on backend and frontend and I got page not found error when I tried this implementation. I would appreciate your help. thanks for the awesome work!

code
https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/2355

Answer (score 2):

This is the same problem [discussed in this FAQ](https://docs.feathersjs.com/faq/readme.html#i-always-get-a-404-for-my-custom-middleware).

> Just like in Express itself, the order of middleware matters. If you
>   registered a custom middleware outside of the generator, you have to
>   make sure that it runs before the notFound() error midlleware.

This means that

```
app.use(express.notFound());
```

Always has to be the last `app.use` call.